# iOS trigger orientation change event

Tags: ios, orientation

I have 2 UIViews. The first supports only portrait. The second both portrait and landscape. To achieve that i change the return value of `supportedInterfaceOrientations` so that it gives the right orientations depending on what view i am.

When i change from screen 2 to screen 1 the view remains in a buggy landscape form, however when i rotate the device the View actually rotates to portrait and is locked there correctly. The reason for that is that when i rotate the device a rotation change event will be triggered.

my question: Is there a way to programmatically trigger a orientation change event?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` on view 1:

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
 {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
 }
```

Comment: Im not sure. I think the problem is not that the orientation is not configured right. I think its just not updating. I will give it a look anyway. I tell you after if it has worked.

Comment: Hey dear user2462592, so did it work out? how could you solve your problem?

Comment: For anyone having problem, adding this method to my controller has worked for me but I needed to call WillAnimateRotation method as well whenever I needed the screen to be redrawn.